# Setting the ItemsSource of a ListBox in IronPython using a custom class

Tags: c#, python, wpf, ironpython

My ultimate goal is to convert this following code from C# to IronPython (Source: https://wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/responding-to-changes/):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfTutorialSamples.DataBinding
{
    public partial class ChangeNotificationSample : Window
    {
        private List<User> users = new List<User>();

        public ChangeNotificationSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            users.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe" });
            users.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe" });

            lbUsers.ItemsSource = users;
        }

        private void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            users.Add(new User() { Name = "New user" });
        }

        private void btnChangeUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(lbUsers.SelectedItem != null)
                (lbUsers.SelectedItem as User).Name = "Random Name";
        }

        private void btnDeleteUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(lbUsers.SelectedItem != null)
                users.Remove(lbUsers.SelectedItem as User);
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Pertinent XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="lbUsers" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ListBox>
```

So far, here is what I've been able to work out using information from http://palepoli.skr.jp/wp/2009/06/28/wpf-listview-databinding-for-ironpython/:

```
import wpf
from System import *
from System.Collections.Generic import *
from System.Windows import *
from System.Windows.Controls import *
from System.Windows.Data import *
from System.ComponentModel import *
from System.Collections.ObjectModel import *

from System.Windows import Application, Window

class NotifyPropertyChangedBase(INotifyPropertyChanged):
    PropertyChanged = None
    def __init__(self):
        (self.PropertyChanged, self._propertyChangedCaller) = make_event()

    def add_PropertyChanged(self, value):
        self.PropertyChanged += value

    def remove_PropertyChanged(self, value):
        self.PropertyChanged -= value

    def OnPropertyChanged(self, propertyName):
        self._propertyChangedCaller(self, PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))


class User(NotifyPropertyChangedBase):

    @property
    def Name(self):
        return self._Name

    @Name.setter
    def Name(self, value):
        self._Name = value
        self.OnPropertyChanged("Name")





class MyWindow(Window):


    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')

        self.users = ObservableCollection[User]()

        temp = User()
        temp.Name = "Test"
        self.users.Add(temp)


        lbUsers.ItemsSource = users




if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

However, this code crashes on the creation of the "self.users" object.  I've discovered that if I initialize ObservableCollection using str and make appropriate changes to the input of the Add function and DisplayMemberPath of the XAML, the code runs fine, but I'm interested in working with custom classes.  From the various articles I've seen online, there does not seem to be a consensus for using ItemsSources and ObservableCollection in IronPython, so I am hoping someone could help me clarify where my issue is.